# What is the difference between "Certified" and "Ready" hardware?  

Tags: certification

What is the difference between "Certified" and "Ready" hardware for Ubuntu?

[Ubuntu Certified](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/)

Answer (score 6):

It's explained in the right column:

> Ubuntu certified
>
> OEMs submit systems to Canonical's testing facility where [certification testing and validation](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/test-suite) is performed by Canonical engineers.
>
> Ubuntu ready
>
> To become Ubuntu Ready, OEMs self-test using Canonical's [certification test suite](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/test-suite) and submit results to Canonical for validation.

Summary: "Ubuntu certified" means that the hardware was tested by Canonical, where hardware with "Ubuntu ready" is tested by the manufacturers themselves and validated by Canonical.

Answer (score 3):

In the Ubuntu Ready programme, the testing is done by the system manufactures that then gets reviewed by Canonical certification engineers, while for Ubuntu Certified, the systems are test

The Ubuntu Ready programme, however, is going to be discontinued in 11.10. One of the reasons to discontinue the programme is because it is confusing for users to have two different programmes. This is explained in the [official Canonical blog](http://blog.canonical.com/2011/07/18/ubuntu-certification-is-changing/).

Answer (score 2):

From ubuntu website:

Certified: OEMs submit systems to Canonical's testing facility where certification testing and validation is performed by Canonical engineers.

Ready: To become Ubuntu Ready, OEMs self-test using Canonical's certification test suite and submit results to Canonical for validation.

Comment: Ah: from http://www.canonical.com/engineering-services/certification/hardware-certification